# Does the sequence $f_1=x^2+1$ , $f_{n+1}=(f_n)^2+1$ contain only irreducible polynomials?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, dynamical-systems, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the sequence

$$f_1=x^2+1$$

$$f_{n+1}=(f_n)^2+1$$

of polynomials over the integers.

> Is $f_n$ irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$ for all $n\ge 1$ ?

With PARI/GP, I found out that upto degree $4\ 096$, all the polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$. Obviously , the polynomials don't have real roots and are all even. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you just wake up in the morning and the idea came to you? :-) Some motivation/background would be nice...

Comment: @Cauchy No. I played around sequences $x_1=a$ $x_{n+1}=(x_n)^2+1$ and wondered about the primes such a sequence contains depending on the start value $a$. Since reducible polynomials produce composite numbers (upto finite many exceptions) we could rule out primes for a specific $n$ for almost every start value $a$

Comment: by the Rational root theorem and the obvious fact that all $f_n$ are monic polynomial if there is a rational $\in \mathbb{Q} $ root(zero) it must be integer $\in \mathbb{Z}$, does this help ?

Comment: @Ahmad It is rather obvious that these polynomials have no *real* root. Note that $f_n(x)\ge n$.

Comment: @ajotatxe very smart idea, why not write an answer.

Comment: @Ahmad Because a polynomial with no roots can be reducible. Example: $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: @ajotatxe very nice, i am not that great in polynomials.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM We square the polynomial $f_n$ and add $1$ to get the next polynomial, so for example $$f_2=(x^2+1)^2+1$$

Comment: $f_n(x) = f_k(f_{n-k}(x))$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true.

From Ayad, McQuillan, *Irreducibility of the iterates of a quadratic polynomial over a field* ([here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa93/aa9317.pdf)), a polynomial is said to be stable over $K$ if all its iterates are irreducible over $K$.

Let $f(X)=X^2-lX+m$ and $d=l^2-4m$ its discriminant.

> **Theorem 3**: If $d=0 \pmod 4$ and $d\neq0 \pmod{16}$, then $f$ is stable over $\mathbb Q$.

In our case, $l=0$, $m=1$, hence $d=-4$ and the theorem applies.

Comment: Very nice! (+1 and accept)